# Installed Anaconda on an M1 MacBook Pro but I can't find the Navigator in applications - why is this happening?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, anaconda3

I installed Anaconda 3 via the graphical user interface and after the download was completed, I can't find the Anaconda Navigator app anywhere on the computer. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling and met the same issue.

Comment: Check this [tutorial on installing anaconda on Mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6ZAv7hBH6Y&ab_channel=UnderstandingData) and see if there is anything you did differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda distribution supports MacBook Pro M1, but does not support Qt yet – Anaconda Navigator and Spyder will not be available.

Check the following link Please!

https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1

Comment: That is outdated information: **osx-arm64** builds for `qt` and `anaconda-navigator` are both available through the `defaults` (`anaconda`) channel. For example, https://anaconda.org/anaconda/qt. User may need to manually specify `conda install anaconda-navigator` after installing an Anaconda distribution, since the distribution may not yet explicitly specify to install this.